# Can't base64 decode utf-8 special characters properly

Tags: java, android, python, encoding

I have an Android app that communicates with a Python backend. It sends a base64 encoded string and the Python server decodes it. It currently works fine for 0-9 A-z characters, but if I put in a æ, ø or other special characters, the entire output is garbled. Im assumning its an encoding issue, but I cant quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Java:

```
public static String encodeToBase64(String text){
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return text;
        }

        text = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return text;

    }
```

And Python

```
subject = base64.b64decode(subject)
body = base64.b64decode(body).decode('UTF-8')
```

Can anyone see what the issue is here?

On the Java side, if I send in the following text, everything is fine

```
input = "[Mar 6 - 15:45:5] hello world"
output = "W01hciA2IC0gMTU6NDU6NV0gaGVsbG8gd29ybGQKQmF0dGVyeTogNTAuMCU="
```

However, the following does not work.

```
input = "[Mar 6 - 15:46:54] hello wørld"
```

When Python decodes it it gets the following:

```
[Mar 6 - 15:46:54] ᘀ栀攀氀氀漀 眀爀氀
```

It gets encoded as

Comment: Can you include sample data that shows the issue, please?

Comment: Well what is the exact nature of the original string, what is the base64 version, and what *exactly* does Python show? You should trace the *exact* data at every stage, so you can work out what's going wrong. (As an aside, it doesn't help that you're using the `text` variable for both the base64 version and the original text; nor does it help that if it can't find UTF-8 it just returns the original text.)

Comment: I can see the text `hello wørld` in there **in UTF-16 bytes**. You failed to encode that to UTF-8 properly somewhere.

Comment: `>>> print u"ᘀ栀攀氀氀漀 眀爀氀".encode('utf-16-be').decode('utf-16-le')` produces `hello wrl`. So the UTF-16 byte order is swapped and some data is lost there, but you get the idea.

Comment: Since it is *Java* that handles Unicode data internally as UTF-16, this problem lies entirely on the Java side.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm, but isnt that what getBytes("UTF-8"); takes care of?

Comment: @Zygote: I am no Java expert, I don't know. You'll have to debug that area. I also note you failed to show us any Base64 data for that case.

Comment: W01hciA2IC0gMTY6MjY6MzRdIOGAgOaggOaUgOawgOawgOa8gOKAgOecgAp is the base64 encoded string from java. I cant seem to properly decode with any tool, so I guess the issue here is indeed the Java side implementation.

Comment: *Facepalm* It seems like the issue here is the Android Emulator. I was feeding the emulator data through telnet and I discovered that Android isnt receiving the special characters properly at all. Thanks for all your help though. Once I verify that the code works Ill post an answer.

Comment: There is one `=` padding missing, after which I can decode the data as Base64 getting a UTF-8 encoded version of the Mojibake you produced, truncated.